# Add a string to top of the file

Tags: swift, append

I want to add a string at the beginning of my file and end of the file.

I am appending a string at the end like this,

```
func writeToFile(content: String, fileName: String) {

    let contentToAppend = content+"\n"
    let filePath = NSHomeDirectory() + "/Documents/" + fileName

    //Check if file exists
    if let fileHandle = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePath) {
        //Append to file
        fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()

        fileHandle.write(contentToAppend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    }
    else {
        //Create new file
        do {
            try contentToAppend.write(toFile: filePath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            print("Error creating \(filePath)")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `fileHandle.seek(toFileOffset: 0)` but it removes my first line from the file. I want to add 2 line of text at the beginning of the file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a file handle to insert data into an existing file. It only supports overwriting all or part of the file or appending to the end of the file.

You need to create a new file by first writing the string you want at the beginning, then writing the contents of the existing file, then writing the string you want at the end.

Here is an extension you can use to add the contents of an existing file to a file handle. It is assume the file handle is already setup for writing.

```
extension FileManager {
    func appendContentsOfFile(at fileURL: URL, to outputHandle: FileHandle) throws {
        let inputHandle = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: fileURL)
        while true {
            let data = inputHandle.readData(ofLength: 4096)
            if data.isEmpty {
                break
            } else {
                outputHandle.write(data)
            }
        }
        inputHandle.closeFile()
    }
}
```

Using this, the solution to your question is achieved with the following steps:

1. Create a FileHandler for writing to a new file.
2. Write the data for the starting string.
3. Call FileManager.default.appendContentsOfFile(at: someFileURL, to: yourFileHandle) to add the existing file.
4. Write the data for the ending string.
5. Close the handle.
6. Optionally, delete the old file, rename the new file.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I created file1 with my beginning content then I added string at the end to my original file. Now what I am looking is to add original file at the end of file1(beginning text file). Let me know if I m not clear.

Comment: If the original file is small, load into a `Data` instance and write that data to the new file just like you write the string data. If the file is too large, use a file stream and read the stream in manageable chunks of data.

Comment: My original file is large. I need to go for the second option you suggested. Is it possible to provide a sample code or document to follow?

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you much.